# How to search a database value from angular 2?

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

I have an angular2 application and want to add a search function.

I have added a TextBox and a button. The button click get's the value from that textbox and pass it to backend(built in express framework).

My code as below.

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" formControlName="search/> 
<button type="submit" name="button"(click)="search()">Search</button>
```

Then the button click event,

```
search(){
  const activity = {
  search: this.form.get('search').value,
}
this.Service.getSearch(activity.search).subscribe(data => {
  this.activitylist = data.activities;
```

Then there's a service class to access the backend. How i am do this is, I'm using params. to get the value from the backend.

Now i want to do this query.

Give my url a rest url format.

When someone search, URL Should be like

```
'/allActivities?search='+search
```

something like this?

Can somebody tell me how to do this? How to pass this from angular 2 front end to express API?

Comment: Please post question correctly , language is unclear and post some more code to get help easily.

Comment: Use the `HttpModule` or the new [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule) to fetch data from a server.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Http Module to get data from Backend

**eg-**

**Enable HTTP module**

**app.module.ts**

```
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";

imports:[HttpModule]
```

**In Component**

```
searchField: FormControl;
coolForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private service: Service){}

this.searchField.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => this.service.getUser(term))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    this.result = result;
  });
```

**Service**

```
 constructor(private http:Http) { }

getUser(user:string){
    return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/'+user) // using git as reference
    //you can also use your query params here
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
```

**Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="coolForm">
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="Search Github Repo" formControlName="search">
  </md-input-container>
</form>
```

you can see the working example of the same in this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/faq) serach for Github